# OneNote for Windows 10: moving a notebook from one account (personal) to another (business)

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-onenote

I have two OneNote for Windows 10 accounts.  One appears to be business, the other personal.  In the beginning I stored business-related files in my personal account (out of ignorance).   Now I want to get them out of my personal account and into my business account.   I have a new personal computer and I don't want the business notebooks there, I want my personal notebooks to appear.  And I don't want my personal notebooks visible on my business computer.

There are a lot of instructions for doing this on the web, but none have worked.  One reason is the awful confusion between OneNote for Windows 10 and OneNote 2016.   Another is that some questions/answers don't seem to specify if they are talking about business or personal accounts. Furthermore, it appears that Microsoft has no qualms about changing the UI and features such that instructions that may once have worked refer to menu items and other items that do not exist anymore.  This may be true only for OneNote for 2016.  It's a confusing mess.

Can someone please give me instructions for doing this?  I can use OneNote for Windows 10 or OneNote 2016.  If you refer to files on my local drive or my OneDrive, please be explicit about the path.  Don't say "open File Explorer and navigate to your OneNote files in OneDrive"  or "...in C:\Users<username>\OneNote".   I've tried all that, and I cannot find my OneNote files either business or personal,  "for Windows 10" or "2016".

Help greatly appreciated,  Many TIA.

**update**

I *may* have managed to use OneNote 2016 to export a notebook, and then open it in OneNote 2016 in the other account.   This *appears* to have put a notebook in my business account where I want it.    If I'm confindent that that's what happened, how can I delete the notebook from my personal account?

Comment: It’s only possible to move notes with the Desktop version.  The UWP version doesn’t support this feature.  The process is extremely simple, sadly don’t have a desktop, and won’t have one for 3 days.  Researched this problem a few months ago so I know it’s only possible with the desktop version

Comment: @Ramhound   #sigh# Yet more terminology designed, it seems, to drive me to drink. Which is the desktop version?

Comment: The one that isn’t a UWP application? These are common terminology, that has existed for years, cannot use any simpler terminology

Comment: @Ramhound is one of them OneNote for Windows 10 and the other Windows 2016?   To someone who is new to this it makes no difference how long the terminology has been around.

Comment: Make sure save the notes to local first, and then synchronized to the cloud. Or you could also post this thread in [Microsoft OneNote support](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_onenote?sort=LastReplyDate&dir=Desc&tab=All&status=all&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=All&isFilterExpanded=false&page=1) for further help.

Comment: Only one of those applications is a UWP.  OneNote 2016 is the desktop application.  You should be able to delete a note using a similar action you used to create it.  Don’t have a PC in front of me.  Microsoft has indeed documented the process.